# Differentiate between Allow Location Access and Allow Location Access (Remember) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, geolocation

In the current [Geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) spec, there is no way to determine if a user has "allowed" or "not allowed" access to location services without calling the same method that will prompt them. The common workaround for this is to store the result of the first prompt in `localStorage`. This way applications can read from `localStorage` to determine if a user has been asked previously, has allowed access, or has not allowed access.

On Chrome, this solution works well enough. On Firefox, there is an extra option presented to users to "Remember this decision".

[image]

In order to correctly determine whether or not the user has enabled location services on an application refresh, I need to know if they decided to "remember" or not in order to correctly present the user with an "Enable Location" UI.

After a location prompt is answered, is there a known method for determining if the decision is "remembered"?